# Moving app folder inside source in nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

As far as I can see, there is currently no way to add `/src/app` as an alternative to the `/app` root directory, as was possible with `/pages`?

Comment: `src/pages` will be ignored if pages is present in the root directory

Comment: Thx but the question is, will this work also with the app (nextjs 13) version?

Comment: Yes, you can do that in Next 13. When generating a new app, the cli even suggests it.